# Lion: Safari brings me to the Googlesearch window when I want to go to next tab via keyboard, what can I do?

Tags: macos, safari

Safari (5.1.1-Lion) enervates me many times every day (= very often!):

Every time when I want to go to the next tab via keyboard command (command+tab/or command+tab+alt when going to the left) the Googlesearch input window is activated first.

That means I've always to type in the command a second time.
(I don't use a trackpad. I'm working with keyboard and mouse/trackball.)

Is there a solution/walkaround???

Answer (score 1):

Jump to next tab:

⌘+Shift+[

Jump to previous tab:

⌘+Shift+]

Shortcuts tested on Mac OS 10.6.5 with Safari 5.0.3 on MacBook Pro.  Should still apply in Lion with 5.1

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Unfortunately I don't understand the meaning of ]/[Jump, sorry. Maybe these are other keys on my german keyboard - I don't know them.   But I just tried the first part of the thing: command+shift+arrow left/right and that does the job too. Thank you for the tip

Comment: I will make it clearer in the answer - thanks for pointing it out.  The "[" keys are the square brackets, not "(" or "{".

Comment: Hi stuffe, thanks again.   On my keyboard these brackets are only to realize as an acrobatic combination of keys. I tried, but can nearly not use it. Stop, that's wrong: I just tried it for another time and it doesn't lead to the result. ....Probably more difficult than hoped: the different international key assignments demand another solution, I guess. ----- Can you please tell me, which other assignment are on the same key on your keyboard? Perhaps that might help.